# g++ no matching function call error

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

I've got a compiler error but I can't figure out why.

the .hpp:

```
#ifndef _CGERADE_HPP
#define _CGERADE_HPP
#include "CVektor.hpp"
#include <string>

class CGerade
{

protected:
    CVektor o, rv;

public:

    CGerade(CVektor n_o, CVektor n_rv);

    CVektor getPoint(float t);

    string toString();
};
```

the .cpp:

```
#include "CGerade.hpp"

CGerade::CGerade(CVektor n_o, CVektor n_rv)
{
    o = n_o;
    rv = n_rv.getUnitVector();
}
```

the error message:

```
CGerade.cpp:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘CVektor::CVektor()’
CVektor.hpp:28: note: candidates are: CVektor::CVektor(float, float, float)
CVektor.hpp:26: note:                 CVektor::CVektor(bool, float, float, float)
CVektor.hpp:16: note:                 CVektor::CVektor(const CVektor&)
CGerade.cpp:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘CVektor::CVektor()’
CVektor.hpp:28: note: candidates are: CVektor::CVektor(float, float, float)
CVektor.hpp:26: note:                 CVektor::CVektor(bool, float, float, float)
CVektor.hpp:16: note:                 CVektor::CVektor(const CVektor&)
```

Comment: The usual moan that names like _CGERADE_HPP are reserved in C++ - got to automate this.

Comment: The other usual moan that the applicable source code isn't provided, the error being in line 10 of CGerade.cpp while only the first 7 lines are in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of it, your `CVektor` class has no default constructor, which `CGerade` uses in your constructor:

```
CGerade::CGerade(CVektor n_o, CVektor n_rv)
{ // <-- by here, all members are constructed
    o = n_o;
    rv = n_rv.getUnitVector();
}
```

You could (and probably should) add one, but better is to use the initialization list to initialize members:

```
CGerade::CGerade(CVektor n_o, CVektor n_rv) :
o(n_o),
rv(n_rv.getUnitVector())
{}
```

Which specifies how the members are initialized. (And above, it was defaulting to the non-existent default-constructor.)

Comment: I don't agree with the "and probably should". It may make perfect sense for `CVektor` to have no default constructor.

Comment: @Gorpik: Why not? (0, 0, 0) is perfectly default.

Comment: Save the Unicorns: In spite of the name, we don't really know what is the purpose of class `CVektor`. There are lots of classes around which should not have a default constructor.

Comment: @Gorpik: The function that returns a `CVektor` is called `getPoint`, `CVektor` has a member called `getUnitVector`, and it has a constructor that takes 3 floats. I think it's pretty obvious it's a normal 3-Vector class.

Answer (score 2):

Your `CVektor` class has no default constructor (that is, one that takes no arguments), so your `CGerade` constructor can't call it.  Since you're not explicitly calling a `CVektor` constructor in your initializer list, the compiler implicitly tries to call the default constructor, but there is none to call, so you get an error.

You should explicitly call the `CVektor` copy constructor using an initializer list:

```
CGerade::CGerade(CVektor n_o, CVektor n_rv)
    : o(n_o), rv(n_rv.getUnitVector())
{
    // empty body
}
```