# C++ Array of interface base classes for chess

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, interface

I am chasing error messages around in circles trying to figure out how I can get what I need working.

I am making a chess game where each chessmen is a class and there is an interface class named Piece.

**Piece.h**

```
class Piece {
public:
    virtual ~Piece() {};
    /*
     * Verifies the move on a per-piece basis. If the move is valid, make the changes on the board and return true, false otherwise.
     *
     * @param b             Reference to the board
     * @param toLocation    Where to move the piece
     * @return bool         If the move is valid
     */
    virtual bool move(Board &b, std::pair<int, int> toLocation) { return false; }

protected:
    Piece(GameData::Color _c) { c = _c; }
    GameData::Color c;
};
```

**Pawn.h**

```
class Pawn : Piece {
public:
    Pawn(GameData::Color _c);
    virtual ~Pawn();
    bool move(Board &b, std::pair<int, int> toLocation);
};
```

I cannot get this setup working though.

I get an error:

```
Pawn::Pawn(GameData::Color _c) : c(_c) {
no matching function for call to Piece::Piece()
```

I change the visibility of Piece to:

```
class Pawn : public Piece
```

But I get loads more errors where I don't have an empty constructor for piece again.

I am setting this up to try and make a 2D array of Pieces to represent the board:

```
board = new Piece**[SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    board[i] = new Piece*[SIZE];
/* Setup initial positions */
board[0][0] = new Rook(GameData::BLACK);
```

Which is why I cannot make the move method purely virtual.. because the **new Piece*** call complains that it needs to be implemented.

Comment: `Pawn::Pawn(GameData::Color _c) : Piece(_c) {}`.

Comment: That easy eh.. thanks haha..

Comment: One of a zillion duplicates: [g++ no matching function call error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685172/g-no-matching-function-call-error)

Comment: You should make the method virtual and find out why new Piece*[SIZE]; complains as it shouldn't. And making particular method pure virtual is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because your `Pawn` constructor does not specify how its `Piece` base sub-object should be initialized. Normally not specifying this will result in the default constructor of `Piece` being called, but `Piece` does not have a default constructor, hence the error.

Fix it by being explicit:

```
Pawn::Pawn(GameData::Color _c) : Piece(_c) {}
```

This tells the compiler that you want to initialize the base by calling the constructor that accepts a `Color`; that constructor will take care of assigning `c = _c` so (given the simplified example) you are left with an empty body for `Pawn::Pawn`.

Incidentally, since you intend to use `Piece` not only as a base class but also to expose an interface to the outside world, `Pawn` should derive publicly from `Piece`.

Comment: I was also going to recommend they change Move to pure virtual in the base class as well.  Since it returns false as default behavior, they intend for it to be overwritten and I doubt they ever want to have just a "Piece" object sitting around with no functionality.

Answer (score 5):

You have to call the `Piece` constructor via the [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

```
Pawn(GameData::Color _c): Piece(_c) {}
```

Or create a default constructor and initialize the values via a method. Your choice.